# Server logs: Looking for endless redirect Loop

Tags: redirect, ssh, terminal

One of my Drupal websites homepage (just the homepage) is constantly redirecting when the site is visited. Tends to happen randomly. Which I don't understand why it would do this. I talked a bit on the Drupal community and it is said to be a server issue. Not Drupal.

```
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

I don't currently have CPanel access to check the server logs though. I am somewhat fluent in terminal and I have root SSH access to the server.

Where and what commands would I have to run to find and access the logs that could possible help me figure where to start with fixing this? Would they just be located in /var/? What would I be looking for once I get access to the logs, just a steady stream of the duplicated IP address that it keeps being redirected too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out this IS a Drupal Commerce Kickstart core issue.

---

Found follow errors in php logs:

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini 

PHP Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in public_html/dev/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/search_api_db/servic‌​e.inc on line 970
```

Got the redirect loop to stop after increasing the max_input_vars to 9000. I feel it's more of a bandaid fix though. So I'm taking this further into the Commerice Kickstart community.